# multi-valued exercise continuity

Tags: functional-analysis

$(\Omega,\Sigma )$ measurable  space,$X$ a metric separable space, $C \subset X$ closed convex subet of X.
$$F:\Omega \times C \rightarrow P_{cl,b}(X) $$ ($ P_{c,b}(X)$ is set of all subsets  of X which closed and bounded)

$\omega \rightarrow F(\omega, .)$ measurable.\

$x \rightarrow F(.,x) $ continuous.

prove that $\forall \epsilon >0, \ \ G: \Omega \rightarrow P(C)$ measurable.
st $G(\omega )=\left\lbrace x \in C, \ d(x, F(\omega,x)) \leq \epsilon
\right\rbrace \ \ \ \forall \omega \in \Omega. $

Comment: With "$P_{c,\,b}(X)$ is parts of $X$", do you mean subsets of $X$? What is $d$ in your definition of $G$? A metric? Thus, is $X$ metrizable?

Comment: Yes. $P_{c,b}(X)$ is subsets of X . 
$d$ metric on X

Comment: Nice question! I like it!